# Dresden OCL Load Constraints

Tags: constraints, aspectj, ocl

I am trying to learn Dresden Ocl. When I try to Generate AspectJ Constraint Code. I am getting the following error

> The selected model does not contain any constraint. Please load
>   constraints first.

Please let me know what is the issue here. Also, if you can point me to step by step tutorial which walks through "Generate AspectJ Constraint Code" that would be great too.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late, but Dresden OCL provides a manual ([pdf](http://www.dresden-ocl.org/update/manual.pdf)), that contains both, developer and user documentation. See p. 49, Chapter 4 (ASPECTJ CODE GENERATION).

Dresden OCL 3.3.0 is released for a while and there is work on the continues build to achieve a continous release. Be aware that the current 3.3.0 does not contain AspectJ parts, due to maven shortcomings in the AspectJ code generation process. It will be available with Dresden OCL 3.3.1 release.

If you need further information, see the webpage of Dresden OCL (www.dresden-ocl.org). Or visit the [Github page of Dresden OCL](https://github.com/dresden-ocl/dresdenocl).

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems. For me only start work with eclipse luna and java 1.6.